# Texture is rendering not correctly with meshStandardMaterial three.js

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to render texture to material but it rendered is not correctly, maybe my texture is wrong, but when i add the texture in blender it renders correctly. I don't know why.

Sorry I just learned threejs, but the current project needs to render in 3d. So I came here to ask if anyone has a solution, please help me.

[image]

Here is my Codesanbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/hero-kdhox?file=/src/App.js

The texture I have added in Blender something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiSuT.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must flip your textures vertically, threejs will by default flip them when you import them using 'useLoader' there is a property [flipY](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture.flipY) for textures but it hasn't been working reliably

Your best bet is to flip them vertically manually before importing

Alternatively, pack the textures in your GLB on blender itself

Comment: I have flipped manually, and also console log the texture it show me `flipY: true`, but the same

Comment: Oh, I have set all textures flipY prop to false, and now it works, thank for your keyword :))